# Is this the correct way to design a map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am designing a MapReduce in Apache Hadoop. I am given data that contains: Customers’ unique identifier, their Post Code, Date of Purchase, and the product they have purchased.

A sample data looks like this:

```
CustId 10001,
PostCode 111111,
DoP 19/11/2000,
ProdP 1
```

I want to analyze this query:

```
How many products a customer has purchased in the last 12 months?
```

I have come up with this design for MapReduce in Apache Hadoop: [MapReduce Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcp6A.png).
I want to check whether the (Key, Value) pairs that I have used are correct or not and whether this design handles all the edge cases or not.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mapreduce InputFileFormat requires individual records on single lines and cannot easily take data from separate lines. For example, `ProdP 1` wouldn't be known for `CustId 10001`

Instead, use a proper CSV file, for example, containing data like this

```
10001,111111,19/11/2000,1
```

Of course, mapreduce really is not beneficial for this singular line of a file because Unix tools like `awk` would be far faster...

Also, tools like Hive or SparkSQL should be preferred over mapreduce since it's simply `SELECT SUM(prodp) GROUP BY custId`